# Adding TextView into another layout programatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I am strugling with one problem. I have got one main view with two layouts inside it:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TestMainActivity" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/menuView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add2" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <com.test.board.Board
        android:id="@+id/boardView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/menuView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Board layout is my class which is inhariting from ViewGroup. What I want to achive is to add TextView (or any other Layout elent like Image, button, another layout) into my canvas (borad).

This is how am I doing it now:

```
Button textBold = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        textBold.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                TextView txt1 = new TextView(TestMainActivity.this);
                txt1.setText("Sample text");
                txt1.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                txt1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                myView.addView(txt1);
            }
        });
```

myView is object of class Board.

When I am checking the number of child elements is increasing each time, but I don't see this TextView.

Can someone please tell me, what I have to do to make this text visible?

**EDIT**

It might be a mistake that I didn't put whole onCreat method, where I initialize myView. So there it is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myView = (Board) findViewById(R.id.boardView1);
        myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        myView.refreshView(); //function below

        Button textBold = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        textBold.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                TextView txt1 = new TextView(TestMainActivity.this);
                txt1.setText("Sample text");
                txt1.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                txt1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                myView.addView(txt1);
            }
        });
```

there is refreshView() function just for extra:

```
public void refreshView() {
        // redraw the view
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use a ListView?

Comment: because of two reasons - I want to move and make other stuff with added elements; second - I want to add not only textviews what is mentioned in question.

Comment: Please post your Board class!

Answer (score 0):

`myView` may be an instance of `Board`, but it probably isn't the one that has been inflated and is on-screen. Make sure that `myView` is set like this:

```
myView = (Board)findViewById(R.id.boardView1);
```

Comment: it is like this already. I've just update question - thank you for this answer, that was suggestion to update it.

Comment: Then the problem is probably the way you are drawing the children. If your `Board` class inherits from `ViewGroup` then you probably need to implement a bunch of code to draw the children correctly. That's not my area of expertise so I can't offer any more help. Sorry.